# How to load a color strip to datatable instead of color code?

Tags: jquery, datatable

what is the way to get the color code as a color strip to the datable? In the attached picture it shows how the color code pass to the datatable. I need to replace the code with the relavant color strip. Is it possibole and what is the correct way?

```js
    $("#ServiceCreatorTable").DataTable
        ({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "filter": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": window.ApiUrl + "/ServiceCreator/GetServiceDetails",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": [0],
                "orderable": true,

            }, 
            {
                "targets": [8],
                "searchable": false,
                "orderable": false
            }],

            "columns": [
                { "data": "service_Creator_Id", "name": "Service ID", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "service_Creator_Code", "name": "Service Code", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "service_Creator_Name", "name": "Service Name", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "service_Creator_Desc", "name": "Service Description", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "service_Category_Name", "name": "Service Category ID", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "service_Sub_Cat_Name", "name": "Sub Service Category ID", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "no_of_Sub_Services", "name": "No of Services", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "colour", "name": "Service Colour", "autoWidth": true },

                {
                    'data': null,
                    'render': function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm text-center" onclick="deleteservice(' + row.service_Creator_Id + ')"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>'
                    }
                },

            ]
        });
```

```html
<table id="ServiceCreatorTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive-sm" width="100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>SN</th>
                                        <th>Code</th>
                                        <th>Service Name</th>
                                        <th>Description</th>
                                        <th>Service Category</th>
                                        <th>Sub Service Category</th>
                                        <th>No Of Sub Services</th>
                                        <th>Colour</th>
                                        <th></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
```

[image]

Comment: Try passing a `<div>` element as data instead of the raw color code.
`"<div style='height:20px;width:60px;background-color:#2bdc1e'></div>"`

Comment: {
                    'data': null,
                    'render': function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<div style="height: 20px; width: 60px; position:center; background-color:' + row.colour + '"></div>'
                    }
                },

Comment: It is working now. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing a `<div>` element as data instead of the raw color code.

```
"<div style='height:20px;width:60px;background-color:#2bdc1e'></div>"
```